# In jquery mobile range slider need to display 6 digit value

Tags: jquery-mobile

In the range slider text box i am try to show 5000000 but it is showing only 500000 rest of the digits is available but not visible i try to change the size but the texbox it is rearranging the position of range slider.

```
<form>
    <div data-role="rangeslider">
        <label for="minPrice">Price Range &#40;&pound;&#41;</label>
        <input type="range" name="minPrice" id="minPrice" min="0" max="5000000" value="0">
        <label for="maxPrice">Price Range &#40;&pound;&#41;</label>
        <input type="range" name="maxPrice" id="maxPrice" min="0" max="5000000" value="5000000">
    </div>
</form>
```

How to support value 5000000  without rearrangement of slider.So anyone have idea so that i can solve this issue.I have regenerated the issue in fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/8xVWY/100/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made you a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/8xVWY/110/

Solution for jQuery Mobile version 1.4 + :  http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vJa7Z

**HTML :**

```
<form>
    <div data-role="rangeslider" id="custom-slider">
        <label for="minPrice">Price Range &#40;&pound;&#41;</label>
        <input type="range" name="minPrice" id="minPrice" min="0" max="5000000" value="0">
        <label for="maxPrice">Price Range &#40;&pound;&#41;</label>
        <input type="range" name="maxPrice" id="maxPrice" min="0" max="5000000" value="5000000">
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS :**

```
#custom-slider .ui-rangeslider-sliders {
    margin: 0.5em 100px !important;
}

#custom-slider input.ui-input-text.ui-slider-input {
    width: 70px !important;
}
```

Comment: @Gajotres: Hi, unfortunately this solution is not working for jquery mobile 1.4.2. Could you please update your jsfiddle? Thanks in advance.